# ls - filtered list - total size

Tags: files, ls

I'd like to list all the files beginning with `z`, have their individual filesize, and the total size in the bottom of the list (so I don't have to scroll up like with `ls -s`).

DOS equivalent : `dir z*`

I don't even know if this is done with `ls`, but I suppose there is a simple way to do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `du`:

```
du -d 0 -hc z*
```

- `-d 0`: specifies the maximum level of recursion;
- `-h`: prints the sizes in a human-readable format;
- `-c`: prints a grand total;
- `z*`: globbing pattern which is expanded to the list of files / directories starting with `z` in the current working directory.

```
$ du -d 0 -hc z*
1,2M    zsh-syntax-highlighting
1,2M    total
```